# How to translate labels in generator.yaml file (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony1, yaml

I'd like to ask you, how to translate labels of fields in generator.yaml file. Generally, how to translate content of yaml's files?

Ex:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:
    name:
      label: Name
```

how to make 'name' translatable?

Thx in advance & best wishes from Poland :)

Piotrek

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to do anything. Whether your label comes from generator.yml or from your ModelForm class, in the end your label string goes through sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter::translate method that handles translation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen do the form.post_configure event. I usually have this in my project configuration class like the following:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{

  public function setup()
  {
        $this->dispatcher->connect('form.post_configure', array($this, 'listenToFormPostConfigure'));
  }


  /**
   * Listens to the command.post_command event.
   *
   * @param sfEvent An sfEvent instance
   * @static
   */
  static function listenToFormPostConfigure(sfEvent $event)
  {
    sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers('I18N');

    $form = $event->getSubject();
    $widgetSchema = $form->getWidgetSchema();
    foreach ($form->getValidatorSchema()->getFields() as $fieldName => $validator)
    {
      if (isset($widgetSchema[$fieldName]))
      {
        $label = $widgetSchema[$fieldName]->getLabel() ? $widgetSchema[$fieldName]->getLabel()
            : sfInflector::humanize($fieldName);
        $label = __($label);
        $asterisk = $validator->getOption('required') ? '&nbsp;*' : null;
        $widgetSchema[$fieldName]->setLabel($label . $asterisk . '&nbsp;:');
      }

    }
  }

}
```

This will append an asterisk to the required labels and also translate the labels. Hope it'll be useful to you too.